# last if else statement didnt work

Tags: php, mysqli

hye guys..is there anything wrong with my if else statement..i tried input username that already existed in the database,and it work..also same if i left the textbox epmty..but if a tried enter a valid name,it does not read the else statement..can someone help me..i cant find where is the problem

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php'; 

$username = ($_POST['txtUsername']);

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT companyUsername FROM tblpartner WHERE companyUsername=?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $username);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($username);

if ( $statement->fetch()) {
    echo '<span class="error"> taken</span>';
} else if(empty($username)) {
    echo '<span class="error"> Cannot be empty</span>';
} else 

echo '<span class="success"> available.</span>';


?>
```

Comment: "it does not read the else statement" - What does that mean?   What do you see in the document after entering a valid name?

Comment: it display cannot be empty

Comment: maybe you change you logic. first test if empty, then if in db.

Comment: braces? i.e. else { echo '<span class="success"> available.</span>'; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it mostly right but just got confused because you bind both the input name and the output result to $username.

You want the username *input* to be checked for the "empty" condition, and the username *output* to be checked for NULL to signal that the name is available, if I'm understanding what you want correctly...

So:

```
$username = ($_POST['txtUsername']);

if (empty($username) || ($username == '')) {
     echo '<span class="error"> Cannot be empty</span>';
} else {
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT companyUsername FROM tblpartner   WHERE companyUsername=?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($username);

    if ( $statement->fetch()) {

        echo '<span class="error"> taken</span>';

    } else {

        echo '<span class="success"> available.</span>';

    }



?>
```

Comment: That said, you probably want to store the result of your `fetch()` in a variable so you may distinguish between NULL and false return - then you can detect error conditions...

Comment: thnx your code worked but i have make change so it will display the right thing i want

Comment: $username = ($_POST['txtUsername']);

if (empty($username) || ($username == '')) {
    echo '<span class="error"> Cannot be empty.</span>';
} else {
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT companyUsername FROM tblpartner   WHERE companyUsername=?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($username);

    if ( $statement->fetch()) {

        echo '<span class="error"> taken</span>';

    } else {

        echo '<span class="success"> available</span>';

    }
}

Comment: Yeah, I got the text backward when I first posted, fixed in edit!

Comment: thank u very much..u make my live..i stucks at this problem since yesterday :D